# good method to merge my own git project to the latest official version on github?

Tags: github, merge, updates

For example, I have a hadoop with version 2.7.0. But as you know , hadoop's official version is updating continuously on github.com .My hadoop is managed by enterprise github of my company, which is isolated from github.com. Many secondary development is applied on my own hadoop . But also, I want to make my hadoop updated with newer version ,because some bugs I met was already fixed by latest-version hadoop. Everytime I want to update , for example , I want to update my hadoop from 2.7.0 to an official 2.8.0, I have to download the latest 2.8.0 hadoop, apply my secondary development to it **manually**,yes , absolutely manually, check the modification of my hadoop one by one. But I believe there must be a better solution because it is really time-consuming.

Any one could give me some suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure exactly if this is what you are asking about, but have you forked the official hadoop repository to your own Github? From there you can create a new branch in which you keep your original version. When you create a merge request to your fork of the official branch, it should notify you of the differences between the two in which you can then approve. Here is a link about forking and branching which may help:
http://blog.scottlowe.org/2015/01/27/using-fork-branch-git-workflow/